# .NET Core publish error: "Unable to find msdeploy.exe, please install it and try again"

Tags: windows, docker, .net-core

When I attempt to publish a .NET Core project to the file system in Visual Studio 2015, I get this error:

```
"Unable to find msdeploy.exe, please install it and try again"
```

Answer (score 9):

Download and install `Web Deploy v3.6` (or higher) from Microsoft.

This command in the deployment script needs to be able to find `msdeploy.exe`:

```
Executing command ["C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -source:manifest=...]
```

Ensure that the .exe is in your path (you may have to restart Visual Studio to get it to pick up the new path).

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 installs `msdeploy.exe` by default. This would normally only happen if `Web Deploy` was manually uninstalled at some point.

Comment: And it happens, if you install VS 2017 RC on your machine ;-)

Comment: @Kirsten Interesting, that means that VS 2017 RC1 is not really compatible with .NET Core 1.1 yet?

Comment: Not really. F.e. if you open a new project the csproj file still adresses netcoreapp 1.0. But the last update on visualStudio 2017 RC solves the problem on publishing from VS 2015.